# Android Widget restrictions (doesn't work for 10 000 SMS messages in inbox)

Tags: java, android, android-widget, widget

Does Android Widget have any specific restrictions about the amount of computations it can make?
I have written a widget (Java) which parses SMS messages from inbox and outputs some statistics.
This widget works perfectly on my phone (~200 SMS messages in memory).
One guy has installed my widget. He claims that it doesn't work (widget just doesn't output anything). Also he says that there are about 10 000 SMS messages on his phone.
My question is: can this fact (~10 000 SMS messages being processed) somehow affect the work of my app (e.g. Android always terminates widgets after X iterations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that when you write "widget", you mean what [Android developers refer to as an "app widget"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html).

If you are doing this work in `onUpdate()` or some other lifecycle method of your `AppWidgetProvider`, then you may experience problems of the type that you describe. Those methods are called on the main application thread, and you cannot spend long periods of time on the main application thread. Move the work to an `IntentService` started by the app widget provider.

Comment: Could you please write a link for more detailed description of this?

Comment: @user2419241: I do not know what "this" is. Here is a general discussion of threads in Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads